# Drag n Drop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have begun to learn JavaScript. I have tried the following to drag and drop an image into a dropzone called "dropTarget1"; the image is not draggable. Can you please take a look at my code and advise what I am doing wrong.

```js
var draggable=document.getElementById('dragMe1');

draggable.addEventListener('dragstart',dragStart,false);


var droptarget=document.getElementById("dropTarget1");
 droptarget.addEventListener('dragenter',dragEnter,false);
    droptarget.addEventListener('dragover',dragOver,false);
    droptarget.addEventListener('dragleave',dragLeave,false);
    droptarget.addEventListener('drop',drop,false);


function dragStart(event){
 event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', event.currentTarget.id);
}


    function dragOver(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

  
    function drop(event) {
  var dragMe1=document.createElement("img");
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
        event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  dragMe1.src=data;
  droptarget.appendChild('dragMe1');
        return false;
    }
```

```css
#dropTarget1{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:#DBF272;
 
}

#dragMe1{
 width:300px;
}

#dragMe1 img{
 padding-left:45px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="dropTarget1"></div>



<img id="dragMe1" src="logo1.png" draggable="true" >
<script src="myDragnDrop.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? (E.g., `"Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."`)

Comment: I previewed it in a browser, and notice that the object is not draggable. I am not sure how to test it in a console.. Is the HTML code <div id="dragMe"> written ?

Comment: Press F12 to open the browser dev tools and check for messages in the console there. (Or if you click "Run code snippet" and test it the errors will appear right there on-screen.) Anyway, for one thing, in `dragStart()` you should be using `event.currentTarget` rather than `event.target` because the event is bound to the div, not the img. In `dragEnd()` it doesn't make sense to say `event.target.appendChild(...)` because `event.target` will be the element being dragged, not the element you're dropping it onto.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code should be like this (Explanation in the comments);

```
var draggable=document.getElementById('dragMe1');
var droptarget=document.getElementById("dropTarget1");
var newIm = document.createElement("img"); //Create new image element
/*Subscribe to dragover event. 
  This event fires when a user drag the image over the target */
droptarget.addEventListener('dragover',dragOver,false);
/*Subscribe to drop event. 
  This event fires when a user drop the image on the target */ 
droptarget.addEventListener('drop',drop,false); 

function dragOver(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); //Prevent further drop events from bubbling up the DOM tree
  event.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default behavior of the browser when dropping something on it
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move"; //Specify the feedback that the user receives when a user drags over the target. It can be copy, link, or none
  return false;
}

function drop(event) {
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'); //To retrieve the image URL
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  newIm.src=data; //Write the image URL into the src attribute of newIm
  droptarget.appendChild(newIm); //Add the new created image to the target element
  document.body.removeChild(draggable); //Remove the original image as you're dragging and dropping (moving)
  return false;
}
```

You don't have to subscribe to some events like dragenter, you just need to subscribe to dragover and drop events.

Comment: can you please explain the steps -- like nam.src=data and propagation.

Comment: <img id="dragMe1" src="logo1.png" draggable="true" >

Comment: you don't have to change your html

Comment: This code creates a second img element with the same src, rather than moving the original div/img. Is that what the OP wants?

Comment: this will create a copy. if you want to remove the element you need to use removeChild()

Comment: See the update now. You need to change only the image tag in the html and this will move the image to the yellow div.

Comment: I made the edits as per the suggestions (see edited code above), it still does not work. I want to understand the steps in JS first, before delving in jQuery

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the clarification. I am not sure why do we need to create a new image when I am already using an image with id="dragMe1" on Stage.

Comment: Try this: droptarget.appendChild(draggable); instead of droptarget.appendChild(newIm); and delete the line: document.body.removeChild(draggable); see if it works

Comment: Also, I see that var=draggable is declared but not used afterwards. Is this line >>droptarget.addEventListener('dragover',dragOver,false);

Comment: supposed to be >> draggable.addEventListener('dragover',dragOver,false);

Comment: var draggable is used if you want to create new item and delete the old one. So u use draggable when document.body.removeChild(draggable);

Comment: I think the code to subscribe to the events is ok. Instead, you can modify your div dragtarget html as follows: <div id="dropTarget1" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondrop="drop(event)"></div>. Does that make sense?

Comment: I was successful in achieving the same using the DOM event handler approach. I wanted to try the event listener approach, which is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery, then this [Draggable|jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement) can be a really simlple option.